# How to get all tokens amount separately held on Ethereum address

Tags: blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, etherscan, binance

I am working on a blockchain project related to Ethereum, Binance Network, etc.
The front end is React.js.
I need to get the total balance of user's wallet address (all tokens in that wallet address).
I know that I can get the balance of a specific token with that token address.
But if I don't know which tokens are in user's wallet, how can I get total amount?
Etherscan displays a list of tokens  held by  every addresses as a dropdown. But how to get that list in my app?

Comment: There is no way to do this other than by indexing all transactions or by using external APIs to retrieve the same data.

Comment: Agree with @Gajus - you could try Etherscan's Account API, but it's limited to 10,000 entries, and you'll need to work out the balances from the event logs. There are likely better APIs elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, I also think so with all you. But anyway, I'm looking for the best way to get token list from connected wallet. I'm wondering which api will be better to implement this feature.
I want to ask to everybody, You never faced this problem? How to solve it :)